# Loosing my Win 8 loosing my Ubuntu this is the problem!

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

I have installed Ubuntu with Win 8 but at first step it blocked my Win8! Unfortunately I had to reinstall my Win8 & all of my program.

I've search your site so it seems the problem is because of GRUB! So I've used these codes which I found in your site:

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update`

   and after that these
2. `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (sudo boot-repair &)`

and then boot & repair which unfortunately I've lost my Win 8 again!!!! So I've reinstall my Win but there is no boot menu at starting my PC to choose Ubuntu or Win 8 and my PC runs with Win 8!!!

So please help me to use lovely Ubuntu with my Win 8 together without loosing anything!

Additionally I am Beginner with Ubuntu.

Thank you.

Comment: Usually, such problems are caused by mixing UEFI and BIOS boot modes. If you have Windows 8, then use the 64bit Version of Ubuntu and boot the installation CD/DVD/USB-Stick in UEFI mode. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I sympathize with your problems with Windows, but you really did not have to reinstall it every time. It is not _so bad designed_. All you had to to do was to run it's [Boot Repair](http://askubuntu.com/a/143482/171636) utility then read [some topics](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) about right ways of Ubuntu installation. In your case, you need [this guide](http://askubuntu.com/a/228069/171636).

Answer (score -3):

Oh my god, actually you have made many mistakes
firstly, i have installed ubuntu and it dosnt block windows8, it do dual boot, however, you should tell ubuntu that when installing, this is the first mistake

the second mistake, NEVER FORMAT, DELETE OR WIPE ANYTHING
what i mean how could you delete windows 8 and reinstall it??
i will cry if i have forced to :'(

everything has a fix, ask me when it comes to boot, MBR or some similar problems
im expert in them :D

okay so here we need to fix things out, first GRUB is very cool bootloader

second, look at the internet on how to setup bootloader on a flash drive
i prefer GRUB4DOS

after you made the both and you able to boot from windows 8 and ubuntu using the flash drive, boot up windows 8,

first, make disk check by going to computer and right-click on the windows8 drive and in tools tab you will find disk check, do this cause sometimes the partition might run into error and cause linux to not detect it as an OS, like what happened mine

second, boot from ubuntu, and do bootloader repair, if it still boot up from one OS, then open up windows 8 again and google easyBCD, download and install this program and run it

with it you can manage everything about boot

first do MBR repair (in the program)
then click "edit" tab and delete your windows8/ubuntu boot
then click on "add new" tab and choose windows 8, and choose on what drive windows 8 is, or i might detect it automaticlly, and then go again to "add new" tab and add linux boot

after that, go to "edit boot menu" and edit your boot as you prefer, how much counting time and other settings

after you have done, reboot your system and test it, if it dosn't work, im sorry i cant help you

however, if it worked im not sure if it will boot using normal linux bootloader

and lastly, i might have some errors in this answer cause i'm now using ubuntu so i cant run the program and tell you the exact same thing
tell me if you have faced more problems